# How can setup Graphql Federation with apolloGateway in nestjs

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo, apollo-federation, graphql-federation

Main App imports

```
imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
      gateway: {
        supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
          subgraphs: [
            { name: 'users', url: 'http://localhost:3331/graphql' },
            { name: 'homes', url: 'http://localhost:3332/graphql' },
          ],
        }),
      },
    }),
  ],`
```

2 sub app config

```
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
    driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
    autoSchemaFile: {
      federation: 2,
    },
  }),
]
```

It gives this error

> couldn't load service definitions for "homes" at http://localhost:3332/graphql: 400: Bad Request
> at somelse\estate\node_modules@apollo\gateway\src\supergraphManagers\IntrospectAndCompose\loadServicesFromRemoteEndpoint.ts:77:15
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async Promise.all (index 1)

I need help to solve this or any better way to do it.

Comment: try see https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/518e644f8688334f496d793cfb44e2ea7ad738e5/sample/31-graphql-federation-code-first